# How to upgrade c++ compiler version in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019 generates an error when I try to build a project that I downloaded from github. The author of the github repository says that upgrading my c++ compiler version might solve this problem.

In the About tab in Visual Studio it says  "Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA811". Is this the compiler version? And how do you upgrade the compiler?

"Desktop development with C++" was downloaded with "Get Tools and Features" a few days ago.

Please see the picture below for more detailed information about the error.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html

Comment: Thank you for that. I have Cuda 11.1 already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to extensions, then type ms-vscode.cpptools in the search bar.

Click on the C/C++ extension, and to the right of Uninstall, there should be a gear icon. Click it.

A dropdown menu should open. Select Extension Settings.

Now click in the search bar (sometimes it makes you click twice before you can type without replacing the extension filter) and type  cppStandard.

From here, you should see two options, one for Cpp Standard, and one for C Standard.

Change Cpp Standard to your desired version.

Comment: There are three tabs in the Extentions menu, Nsight, Manage Extentions and Customize Menu. Only Manage Extentions had a search field in it, but when I searched for "ms-vscode.cpptools", it says "no Items found".